# UITextView Copy option not showing in top iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, copy, uitextview, uimenucontroller

Am working in message based iPhone app. I have added `UITextView` to show the messages typed by the user. This app allows the user to `copy the messages`. Whenever the user selects the messages in the `bubbles the Copy option showing in middle of UITextView`. How to show the Copy option in Top of the TextView?

[image]

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gopinath, this is in-built. You cannot change the default behavior. One option could be to write your own custom TextView which would show the copy option at the top. A workaround could be this:

> Just let the user select the text (disable showing 'copy' in the UITextView)
>   You add a button at the top of the bubble 
>   When the user selects the text & clicks on your UIButton 'copy', then copy whatever is the selection programmatically in your own method.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. If you don't mind could you please recommend any good tutorial to do implement the custom UIMenuController in my app? I can't find a good tutorial for this issue? Thanks.